# Why increment and decrement are unary operations

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c

Looks like it's a very strange question, because i've read a lot of documentation, where increment & decrement are unary operations without any explanation.

I could be wrong, but `++i` is similar with `i+=1` (if there aren't any overriding):

```
int i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(++i); // 2

int j = 1;
Console.WriteLine(j+=1); // 2
```

In this case, preincrement is simple syntatic sugar to hide binary operator plus  and `1` as second argument.

Isn't it?

Why does increment and decrement are independent unary operations,- isn't it just binary plus operator with predefined second argument with value `1`?

Comment: They're unary because only one operand is involved: The thing to increment or decrement. Whether it's just syntactic sugar or not depends on the language. In C++ you might have different semantics for those operators.

Comment: Because it is so common operation and people are lazy enough to omit second operand. Note that there is a difference between `++i` and `i++`, so it may allow shorter code in general.

Comment: Good question though. Too bad it's not a programming question!

Comment: Where could i ask this question?

Comment: Another reason could be that the PDP computer used for the original C compiler had auto increment and auto decrement addressing modes, making `i++` free in some cases. Using `i += 2`, for example, required a separate instruction.

Comment: Where would you put the other operand?

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, PDP, VAX and even Motorola 68k CPU had autoincrement/decrement addressing modes, but I agree with DanielJour it's unary because it takes one operand on C language side.

Comment: Note: For user types, In C++, `++x` and `x+=1` may call different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to why `++` and `--` exist in the first place, when normal `+` and `-` could do the job.

With today's compiler optimisation capabilities, it's really all for historical reasons. `++` and `--` date back to the early (but not *earliest*) days of C. [The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) by late **Dennis Ritchie**, author of the C language, gives some interesting historical insights:

> [Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson) went a step further by inventing the `++` and `--` operators,
>   which increment or decrement;
>
> *[...]*
>
> They were not in the earliest versions of [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28programming_language%29), but
>   appeared along the way.
>
> *[...]*
>
> a stronger motivation
>   for the innovation was probably his observation that the translation
>   of `++x` was smaller than that of `x=x+1`.

So the definite reason seems to be lost in the mists of history, but this article by Ritchie strongly suggests that increment and decrement operators owe their existence to performance issues with early compilers.

When C++ was invented, compatibility with C was one of the major design goals by its inventor **Bjarne Stroustrup**, so it's needless to mention that all C operators also exist in C++. As Stroustrup himself says in his [FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#whyC):

> I wanted C++ to be compatible with a complete language with sufficient
>   performance and flexibility for even the most demanding systems
>   programming.

As for C#, one its inventors **Eric Lippert** [once stated here on the Stack Exchange network](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233464/reason-for-post-pre-increment-operator-in-java-or-c) that the only reason for them being supported in C# is consistency with older languages:

> *[...]* these operators are horrid features. They're very confusing; after
>   over 25 years I still get pre- and post- semantics mixed up. They
>   encourage bad habits like combining evaluation of results with
>   production of side effects. Had these features not been in
>   C/C++/Java/JavaScript/etc, they would not have been invented for C#.

---

P.S.: C++ is special because, as you have mentioned (even with the incorrect word "overriding"), you can **overload** all of those operators, which has lead to `++` and `--` taking on slightly different semantics in the minds of many programmers. They sometimes read as "go ahead" ("go back") or "make one step forward" ("make one step backward"), typically with iterators. If you look at the [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) concept in C++, you will see that only the unary `++` is required by it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple.

Unary Operation means the operator will do the operations on only on operand.

Next  i++ and i+=1 both are different actions.

-> when i++ will executes you the compiler will goes the variable location and it will increment the value.

-> i+=1 executes the i and 1 will load into the register/temparory variable and the addition operation will done and the new value will copied into the i address loaction.

So compare to i+=1 will be cost compare to i++.

Comment: I'd rather expect the Compiler should emit exactly the same machine code for `++i` and `i+=1`.

Comment: If the hardware has a specific add-one instruction, called `INC` on some systems, surely the compiler will use that for both operations.

Comment: That is completely design of the compiler, In advanced compilers will convert ++i and i+=1 into same machine code. But original logic behind this operation.

Comment: @Kancham: I don't think a compiler must be particularly advanced for this nowadays.